# Side Text's distance from text box varies

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

When editing a tag wiki, I see the text and the right-hand side:

[image]

It seems normal for now. The text is fine, it gives good, useful advice for new editors and is the right distance away. Or is it. When I scroll further down, the text seem to shift more to the right, widening the white space between the text boxes and the side text:

[image]

What is going on here and can we make the side text's distance from the text boxes constant please? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (latest chrome, IE, FF and Vivaldi on Windows 8.1). The help text remains at a constant distance from the text boxes. Need a reboot?

Comment: You need to make your window smaller then scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to have the window resized to be smaller than the content width, *and* have the horizontal scrollbar all the way to the right in order to reproduce this.

This isn't something we are going to fix - the page is there for editing primarily.